# Bluetooth connection fails with timeout when using Bluetooth 5.0 dongle

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth, winsock2

I am currently using this code to discover, then start up a connection with a bluetooth device using the winsock2 API:

```cpp
  constexpr BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS btDeviceSearchParameters = {
      sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS),
      1,
      0,
      1,
      1,
      1,
      2,
      nullptr
  };

  BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO btDeviceInfo = {sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO), {0}};
  const HBLUETOOTH_DEVICE_FIND btDevice =
      BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&btDeviceSearchParameters, &btDeviceInfo);

  if (btDevice == nullptr) {
    printf("Could not find any bluetooth devices");
    *addr = NULL;
    return false;
  }

  const auto thiswstring = std::wstring(btSerialConfiguration_.name.begin(), btSerialConfiguration_.name.end());
  const WCHAR* wcDeviceName = const_cast<WCHAR*>(thiswstring.c_str());

  do {
    if (wcscmp(btDeviceInfo.szName, wcDeviceName) == 0) {
      printf("A Device found");
      if (btDeviceInfo.fAuthenticated)
      {
        printf("Bluetooth Device authenticated");
        *addr = btDeviceInfo.Address.ullLong;
        return true;
      } else {
        printf("Bluetooth device not authenticated");
      }
    }
  } while (BluetoothFindNextDevice(btDevice, &btDeviceInfo));


  btClientSocket_ = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);

  SOCKADDR_BTH btSocketAddress{};
  btSocketAddress.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
  btSocketAddress.serviceClassId = RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID;
  btSocketAddress.port = 0;
  btSocketAddress.btAddr = addr;

  if (connect(btClientSocket_, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&btSocketAddress), sizeof btSocketAddress) != 0)  // connect to the BT device.
  {
    printf("Failed to connect to bluetooth device");
    return false;
  }
```

I previously had a 4.0 bluetooth dongle, and using this dongle I was successfully able to connect to the device with this code and start receiving data from it.

However, after switching to a 5.0 dongle, this is no longer the case, and when the call to `connect()` is made, I receive this error: `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`

Is there something that I am missing to get a connection going when using a 5.0 bluetooth dongle?

Comment: Dodgy dongle?  It happens.

Comment: @PaulSanders I don't think so, I've had a couple of others run the code with 5.0 dongles and it results in the same error, then works fine when using 4.0 or below dongles.